# How do I specify a default value in one field an sqlalchemy engine INSERT statement?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I use raw SQLAlchemy `engine.execute()` calls to perform INSERT statements, e.g.

```
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://...")
engine.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s %s)", v1, v2, v3, v4)
```

Now lets imagine that the third column is defined as `varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'foo'`
and I want to specify that I want to use that default value.

MySQL has the DEFAULT keyword for this, but how do I tell SQLAlchemy to generate the DEFAULT keyword for one of the variables?

I imagine something like

```
engine.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s %s)", v1, v2, default, v4)
```

But what do I need for `default` here?
(Does SQLAlchemy even support that?)

(I can't use `None` because that gets translated into NULL and violates the NOT NULL constraint. (on MySQL 8)

(I could omit the column like this

```
engine.execute("INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col4) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", v1, v2, v4)
```

but I find it undesirable to generate the list of column names, and I'd prefer to use the DEFAULT keyword.)